# Search number using like from string in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

Field value - 29,21,30,28,32,35,49,50,137

```
SELECT *
FROM `smartspace_pickups`
WHERE `cat_id` LIKE '%37%'    
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

I have field in which the ids are stored comma separated now i tried to fetch data using the above query but it giving me the values with the ID 137 and 371. I only want the value with the id 37 in  the string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM `smartspace_pickups`
WHERE FIND_IN_SET('37',`cat_id`)
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use `FIND_IN_SET(str,strlist)`

```
SELECT *
FROM `smartspace_pickups`
WHERE FIND_IN_SET('37', `cat_id`)  > 0
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set

Answer (score 0):

make your ids field like this (add comma to the starting and ending)

```
,29,21,30,28,32,35,49,50,137,
```

and change your query to

```
LIKE '%,37,%'
```

Comment: And if there is only one value in field?

Comment: @CORRUPT: will be like `,1,`

Comment: Then `WHERE CONCAT(',', cat_id, ',') LIKE '%,37,%'` should work. Yea)